# Delete row after x minutes in mysqli database and php

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I am creating a website in php. I have a database called `database1` I have the tables `cooldown` and `my_table` The `cooldown` table contains the columns `time`(type `Timestamp` default value `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) and `ip`(type int(30) default value `none`). At the end of my code I have `mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM cooldown WHERE time < NOW() -  INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");` which should delete the row after 5 minutes, but it doesn't delete the row. Could this be because the user gets redirected so the php script stops working? Or do I miss something else?

Code:

```
//Test if it is a shared client
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
//Is it a proxy address
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
  $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
  $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
//The value of $ip at this point would look something like: "192.0.34.166"
$ip = ip2long($ip);

//The $ip would now look something like: 1073732954


$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ip FROM cooldown WHERE ip = '$ip'"); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query); 

if ($row) {
   //What page shall the bans be sent to?
   header("Location: http://imnothere.epizy.com/cooldown.html");   //cooldownpage
   exit();
} else {
    $sql1= "SELECT links FROM my_table WHERE Type = 'spotify' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = $conn->query($sql1); //this actually runs the query on the DB, and comes back with a $result object
    if($result1 === false) {
        echo $conn->error();
        }
    $redirect = $result1->fetch_assoc()['links']; //this gets one row from the $result object, and then the 'links' column from that row.
    header("Location: " . $redirect);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cooldown(ip, time) VALUES('$ip', NOW())";
    $result = $conn->query($sql); //this actually runs the query on the DB, and comes back with a $result object
    if($result === false) {
    }
    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM cooldown WHERE time < NOW() -  INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting the delete to be auto scheduled in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query won't delete the rows after 5 minutes, it will delete everything that is 5 minutes or older at the time of the request.

You're probably best moving that line of code to a separate file that is run by `cron` or setup an event in your db to do it say every minute or so.

Comment: Alternatively, you can remove rows prior to `SELECT ip FROM cooldown WHERE ip = '$ip'` which would be easier than setting up some kind of async process.

Answer (score 0):

U can with Cron job , supervisor or schedule time 
Your SQL query  almost as it

```
DELETE FROM cooldown WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

If you want every five minutes, use either

```
*/5 * * * *  fooo
```